# How to determine cycles in a list?

Tags: python, list, cycle

Consider a list of integer indices, `indices`. All elements of `indices` are within the bounds of the list `indices`. All the values in the list `indices` are unique. Example `[2, 0, 1, 4, 3, 5]`.

Given an index, (e.g `0`), move on to `indices[0]` (i.e `2` in the example above). Repeating that can be done indefinitely. A cycle occurs when a move returns to an already visited index. There is always at least one cycle. The sum of the lengths of the cycles is equal to the length of the list `indices`.

I need to create a function `cycles(indices)` that returns a list of all cycles in `indices`.

For the example above, the expected output list is `[[2, 0, 1], [4, 3], [5]]`.

For the list `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, the cycles are trivial and of the form `[[0], [1], [2], [3]]`.

**Note**: The order of the output cycles and the order of the indices do not matter. For example: `[[2, 0, 1], [4, 3], [5]]` is equivalent to `[[3, 4], [0, 1, 2], [5]]`

This is the code I have come up with thus far:

```
def cycles(indices):
    cycles = []
    old_i = []
    i = 0
    while i in range(len(indices)):
        old_i.append(i)
        i = indices[i]
        if i in old_i:
            cycles.append(old_i)
            i = max(old_i) + 1
            old_i = []

    return cycles
```

The problem with my code is that it does not recheck if there is a smaller cycle within the elements of a bigger cycle, if it has already passed the elements of the smaller cycle. Any suggestions as to how to solve this coding problem?

Please note, I am just beginning to learn how to program and I am taking an introductory online course, so I would appreciate simple solutions.

Comment: How could a cycle be part of a larger one? If it's a cycle, it's closed, there's no way it can be part of anything larger...

Comment: I apologize, I expressed that incorrectly. I meant to say that if I have reached a certain element within the original list, and another cycle exists within it, it doesn't take it into account.
For example:
`[12, 0, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 13, 7, 17,14, 2,18, 1, 6, 1, 11, 19, 3, 15]`

This should return:
`[[0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 10, 12, 13, 15, 17, 18, 19], [4, 7, 9], [5, 6], [11, 14, 16]]`

Comment: @EddieEC In your question you've stated "...All the values in the list indices are unique..", but the list contains multiple `1`, `6`, ...

Comment: Again, I apologize. It was a typo.

This is the fixed version:

For example:
`[12, 0, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 13, 7, 17,14, 2,18, 16, 1, 11, 19, 3, 15]`

This should return:
`[[0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 10, 12, 13, 15, 17, 18, 19], [4, 7, 9], [5, 6], [11, 14, 16]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of all the indices you've already visited and ignore them next time. Also, each cycle will have unique indices and no matter where you start in a cycle(12 or 0, if both are in the same cycle), you can always complete the cycle(like a circle).

```py
def gen_cycles(indices):
    cycles = []
    visited = []
    for i in indices:
        if(i in visited):
            continue
        start = i;
        current_cycle = []
        current_cycle.append(start)
        visited.append(start)
        j = indices[start]
        while(j!=start):
            current_cycle.append(j)
            visited.append(j)
            j = indices[j]
        cycles.append(current_cycle)
    return cycles

print(gen_cycles([12, 0, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 13, 7, 17,14, 2,18, 16, 1, 11, 19, 3, 15]))
```

`Output: [[12, 2, 8, 13, 18, 3, 10, 17, 19, 15, 1, 0], [9, 7, 4], [6, 5], [14, 16, 11]]`

Answer (score 2):

If an index is already part of a cycle you can just skip it.

```
def find_cycles(indices):
    """Given a list of indices return a list of cycles."""

    visited = set()
    cycles = []

    for start_ind in indices:

        if start_ind in visited:
            continue

        path = [start_ind]
        next_ind = indices[start_ind]

        while start_ind != next_ind:
            path.append(next_ind)
            next_ind = indices[next_ind]
        else:
            cycles.append(path)
            visited |= set(path)
    return cycles

find_cycles([12, 0, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 13, 7, 17,14, 2,18, 16, 1, 11, 19, 3, 15])
# [[12, 2, 8, 13, 18, 3, 10, 17, 19, 15, 1, 0], [9, 7, 4], [6, 5], [14, 16, 11]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One crude solution, using sets to track which indices we've visited already:

```
def cycles(indices):

    def get_loop(indices, idx):             # this funtion returns a loop, starting from index `idx`
        seen, loop = set(), []
        while True:
            v = indices[idx]                # get index on position `idx`
            if v not in seen:               # have we seen index `v` already?
                loop.append(idx)            # no, add it as part of the loop
                seen.add(v)                 #   update set `seen` with index `v`
                idx = v                     #   set current index `idx` with index `v`
            else:
                break                       # yes, that means we closed the loop
        return loop                         # return this loop

    rv, seen = [], set()
    for i in indices:                       # iterate over all indices
        if i not in seen:                   # is index `i` part of any loop we already have?
            loop = get_loop(indices, i)     # no, so call get_loop() with starting index `i`
            rv.append(loop)                 # we add this loop to the result list
            seen.update(loop)               # update set `seen` with all indices inside this loop

    return rv

print(cycles([2, 0, 1, 4, 3, 5]))
print(cycles([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
print(cycles([12, 0, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 13, 7, 17,14, 2,18, 16, 1, 11, 19, 3, 15]))
```

Prints:

```
[[2, 1, 0], [4, 3], [5]]
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
[[12, 2, 8, 13, 18, 3, 10, 17, 19, 15, 1, 0], [9, 7, 4], [6, 5], [14, 16, 11]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your effort, and this works quite well. But I am looking for a simpler solution because I am taking an introductory course to programming. If you could explain your code, it would be quite helpful!

Comment: @EddieEC I added some comments to explain the code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at `[2, 0, 1, 4, 3, 5]`. In the cycle `[2, 0, 1]` the order of numbers really doesn't matter, so if you start from any of its point, you will get the cycle correctly.

An easy solution for an array of size `N` would be:
1. go through all indices `1..N-1` as `starting_index`
2.   get the cycle beginning at index `starting_index`
3.   if we have already seen this cycle, discard it. Otherwise, remember it.

The function might look like this:

```py
def get_cycles(array):
    cycles = []
    for starting_index in range(len(array)):
        cycle = cycle_at(array, starting_index)
        if not any(are_equal(existing, cycle) for existing in cycles):
            cycles.append(cycle)
    return cycles
```

If you aren't familiar with `any`, the line with `any` does roughly this:

```py
def any(iterable):
  for x in iterable:
    if x:
      return True
  return False
```

We want the cycles `[0, 1, 2]` and `[1, 2, 0]` to be considered equal.
We can write a function that shifts one of them until it matches the second one:

```py
def are_equal(cycle1, cycle2):
    if len(cycle1) != len(cycle2):
        return False
    for i in range(len(cycle1)):
        # [1, 2, 3, 4] -> [2, 3, 4, 1]
        cycle1 = cycle1[1:] + [cycle1[0]]
        if cycle1 == cycle2:
            return True
    return False
```

Or we can use the properties of these cycles and get:

```py
def are_equal(cycle1, cycle2):
    return set(cycle1) == set(cycle2)
```

Because two cycles are equal if and only if they contain the same elements (order doesn't matter -- as the statement says).

Then we need to implement a function that would get the cycle starting at index `i`.

```py
def cycle_at(array, index):
    visited_indices = set()
    cycle = []
    while True:
        cycle.append(index)
        visited_indices.add(index)
        index = array[index]
        if index in visited_indices:
            break
    return cycle
```

We need to remember which indices we visited, and we will store them in a set.
Then we will 'follow the cycle' and traverse the array, adding the `index` to `visited_indices` every time we see a new index.
If at any point we stumble upon a index we have already visited, we end the cycle.

You could improve the performance by not considering the indices that already occur in a cycle as starting indices, because this will eliminate the need for the `are_equal` function and will prevent you from finding the same cycle more than once.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
def cycles(indices):

    sub =[]
    i=0
    result = []
    remaining = indices[:]

    while remaining:
        i = indices[i]
        if(i in sub):
            remaining = [ a for a in remaining if a not in sub]
            result.append(sub)
            sub = []
            if remaining:
                i=remaining[0]

        sub.append(i)
    return result

r = cycles([2, 0, 1, 4, 3, 5])
print(r)
#[[2, 1, 0], [4, 3], [5]]

r = cycles([0,1,2,3,4,5])
print(r)
#[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a perfect problem for graph theory. You can connect elements from the list to their indices and look for connected components in the resulting graph. `networkx` is the most popular Python package for network analysis:

```
import networkx as nx

lst = [2, 0, 1, 4, 3, 5]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(enumerate(lst))
print(list(nx.connected_components(G)))
# [{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}]
```

[image]